# Full width of relative positioned overflowing flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm trying to achieve a line across a horizontal overflowing flex container by making an `absolute` positioned child element with `left` and `right` both set to `0`, this also means the container has to have a `relative` position to contain the absolute positioned element. This is where the trouble starts.

Because the container has a `relative` position, the `right` value of the children is not at the edge of the scroll view, it stops where the the overflow starts.

[CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yowygZ)

HTML Code:

```
<div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
body > div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

body > div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

div > div {
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Is it possible to extend the child to span the entire element, including overflow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make DIV width 100% with scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33904792/cannot-make-div-width-100-with-scrollbar)

Comment: I think using Flex you cannot achieve this like @sergey Denisov. But you can make still make the same using inline-block

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Make child element use 100% of total OVERFLOW height of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45497031/3597276)

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that by using `inline-flex` instead of `flex`

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZdxao)

Stack snippet

```css
body > div {
  display: inline-flex;                /*  changed  */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

body > div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

div > div {
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can add an outer wrapper having `inline-block`

```css
body > div {
  display: inline-block;
}

body > div > div {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

body > div > div::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

body > div > div > div {
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```